# QGIS Legend - distribution of items across columns

Tags: qgis, print-composer, legend

I'm a new QGIS user, still finding my way around. I've created a map and am now preparing for export in print composer.

I've added a legend with ten items, and I want the items to break across five columns evenly. I've specified the number of columns and checked Split Layers, but the end result is three columns of two items, one column of three items, and a final column of one item:

[image]

How can I correct this to display evenly?

Comment: Awesome, glad it helped. Will post the comment as an answer for the convenience of others :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not completely sure why but for 10 legend items, increasing the **column count to 6** instead of 5 seems to split the items equally.

---

Perhaps it is related to hiding the group/subgroup name which seems to count as a legend item itself...